# Wifi sleep policy and wifi lock which one overrides when both conflict?

Tags: android

If an android user has setup the WIFI SLEEP POLICY (KEEP WIFI ON DURING SLEEP) to NEVER, that is wifi should sleep when phone is locked or sleep.

And an app aquires a Wifi wake lock when the phone is not sleeping. While the app keeps the lock if the phones sleeps which setting should prevail ?

Sleep policy ? which tells that wifi should turn off

or the lock aquired by the app ? which attempts to keep wifi ON

There is no clear explanation about this in android documentation any tips would be great as I don't want redundant code in my app

Comment: An interesting question indeed. I just checked on my device, it appears that the app's WifiLock overrides the "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" set to "Never", meaning the Wi-Fi connection is kept active during sleep. Seems to be no official documentation about this behavior.